# Combine 2 result sets in SQL?

Tags: sql

How do I combine the resultsets to return a single result in SQL? For example -

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
SELECT * FROM Table2
```

I want to combine the two resultsets with the columns from the second resultset appended to the first.

Table 1 and Table 2 are not related to each other in any way. If Table 1 has 2 columns and Table 2 has 4 columns, I wanted 6 columns returned total in a single resultset. And if Table 1 has 4 rows and Table 2 has only 2 rows, I want NULLS in Table 2 rows for 3rd and 4th row.

Is it possible?

Edit: I do not know how many columns are present in Table1 and Table2, so cannot use UNION with nulls.

Comment: This sounds like a really horrible thing to do. Can  you explain why you think it is a good idea to do it?

Comment: I have a requirement where a table is actually split into 2 different tables. When returning the values for the table, I want to combine the results of these tables and return to the UI. The other option is to get the 2 datasets back, combine the datatables into a single dataset and use that instead. Just wanted to avoid that. Thanks.

Comment: @tempid. If it is split why doesn't it have the same number of rows and something non arbitrary to join on?

Comment: My bad, you're right, it will have the same number of rows but there are no columns that are common to both tables to join on. It's a bad design but that's how it is.

Comment: @tempid - In that case you could replace the `FULL OUTER JOIN` in my answer with `INNER JOIN` (assuming your RDBMS does support `ROW_NUMBER`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your RDBMS supports `ROW_NUMBER()` you could do something like this.

```
WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY T1id) AS RN1 FROM Table1
),
T2 AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY T2id) AS RN2 FROM Table2
)


SELECT * FROM T1 FULL OUTER JOIN T2 ON RN1 =RN2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but it's probably quite a bad idea to do this. Why not just run two queries?

If you *really* want to do it, join the two result sets on a ROW_NUMBER() field.

Answer (score 0):

Not a general solution, but works if you know your schema:

```
select a1, a2, null as b1, null as b2 from table1
union
select null as a1, null as a2, b1, b2 from table2
```

Comment: I don't think that this is what he wants.